# Make Ubuntu 17.10 gnome panel by "dash to panel" transparent forever

Tags: 17.10, panel, extension, customizer

I want to make Ubuntu panel (made by "dash to panel" extension) transparent forever, Now it's transparent when desktop is active and solid when any kind of window is active, like on this picture(panel is bottom :P).

[image]

Comment: oooh :O What should i do now? delete the question?

Comment: You can leave it here.  It might help someone else.